# Changing dynamic_reconfigure parameters using rosbridge

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosbridge, roslibjs, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a node that includes some dynamically-reconfigurable parameters.  Eventually, I will write a JavaScript GUI that uses [roslibjs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs) and [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/) to interface with this node and the rest of my robot.  I understand that [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) uses ROS services to change the parameters during runtime.

Are there any examples of using roslibjs (or anything that talks to rosbridge) to change dynamically reconfigurable parameters?  I would be grateful to know if this is even possible, because if it isn't, I will have to design my node differently.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289904/changing-dynamic_reconfigure-parameters-using-rosbridge/) by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've investigated this issue on my own.  I couldn't find any existing examples of doing this, however I found that it is indeed possible.  The dynamic_reconfigure package uses a service called [dynamic_reconfigure/Reconfigure.srv](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/dynamic_reconfigure/html/srv/Reconfigure.html).  Since roslibjs can execute services, it can indeed interface with dynamic_reconfigure.

I've taken the time to write a thorough tutorial on how this is done within the roslibjs wiki.  It can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20dynamic_reconfigure%20client%20with%20roslibjs).

It would be nice to have a dynamic_reconfigure API within roslibjs instead of using raw service calls, so I created an issue found [here](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/issues/289) if somebody wishes to implement this functionality.

---

Originally posted by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) with karma: 41 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4